# Python- Suds.Client.Service issue, printing out identifier instead of method text

Tags: python, suds

Hi there I'm fairly new to Python and to web services and I have started work trying to make use of web service methods within a WSDL through Python.  Now when I run the following code what I get returned is the value "".  I'm aiming to get the return value of the GetMessage method instead (a simple Hello World) but instead get this identifier for the method.  Is there a way to get this return value?

```
import logging
import sys
from suds.client import Client
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
url='http://localhost:50774/HostDevServer/HelloWorldService.svc?wsdl'
client = Client(url)
example = client.service.GetMessage
print example
```

I have also tried the following code

```
import logging
import sys
from suds.client import Client
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
url='http://localhost:50774/HostDevServer/HelloWorldService.svc?wsdl'
client = Client(url)
example = client.service.GetMessage()
print example
```

and this returns the following error message:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "suds.client"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\exampleForSuds.py", line 7, in <module>
    example = client.service.GetMessage()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 542, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 649, in send
    result = self.failed(binding, e)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 708, in failed
    raise Exception((status, reason))
Exception: (415, u'Unsupported Media Type')
```

I can get around the first error noted of no handlers by adding:

```
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

But the rest of the error message will remain.  Is there something I'm missing out?  I've searched for hours now and can't really find much of anything that shows a similar problem.

UPDATE:

This is what is printed out in the first code segment:

```
<suds.client.Method instance at 0x02D9FC38>
```

I have tried sebastians idea and what I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\exampleForSuds.py", line 10, in <module>
    example = client.service.GetMessage()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 542, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 649, in send
    result = self.failed(binding, e)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 708, in failed
    raise Exception((status, reason))
Exception: (400, u'Bad Request')
```

The client value for Sebastians idea is the following:

```
Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.4 GA  build: R699-20100913

Service ( HelloWorldService ) tns="http://tempuri.org/"
   Prefixes (1)
      ns0 = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"
   Ports (1):
      (WSHttpBinding_IHelloWorldService)
         Methods (1):
            GetMessage()
         Types (3):
            ns0:char
            ns0:duration
            ns0:guid
```

Update2: The logging per Sebastians request

```
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:sending:
URL:http://localhost:50774/HostDevServer/HelloWorldService.svc
HEADERS: {'SOAPAction': u'"http://tempuri.org/IHelloWorldService/GetMessage"', 'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml; charset="UTF-8"', 'Content-type': 'application/soap+xml; charset="UTF-8"', 'Soapaction': u'"http://tempuri.org/IHelloWorldService/GetMessage"'}
MESSAGE:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><ns1:Body><ns0:GetMessage/></ns1:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
ERROR:suds.client:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns0:GetMessage/>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\exampleForSuds.py", line 11, in <module>
    example = client.service.GetMessage()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 542, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 649, in send
    result = self.failed(binding, e)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 708, in failed
    raise Exception((status, reason))
Exception: (400, u'Bad Request')
```

The code as well for this error:

```
import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport.http').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
from suds.client import Client
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
url='http://localhost:50774/HostDevServer/HelloWorldService.svc?wsdl'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml; charset="UTF-8"'}
client = Client(url,headers=headers)
print client
example = client.service.GetMessage()
print example
```

Final Update:

Found a fix to the problem, it turns out the issue had nothing to do with the python code but the web.config for the web service.  It needs to make use of basicHttpBinding

Comment: Can you update your question showing the output of `print client`?

Comment: `client.service.GetMessage()` seems correct. Enable logging and show the actual code that leads to `400, u'Bad Request'` error and its output.

Comment: That is the logging and code in the OP now

Comment: the code and request look good (except soapaction probably shouldn't be unicode, but it shouldn't cause problems in this case and you don't need `setrecursionlimit()`). Use `logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` to see xml reply from the server. Add `@J.F. Sebastian` to the comment if you'd like to notify me.

Answer (score 3):

To fix `'Unsupported Media Type'` error you could specify a type that the server supports e.g.,:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml; charset="UTF-8"'}
client = Client(wsdl_url, headers=headers)
```

To see what suds actually sends you could configure logging:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport.http').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: I have tried his but in doing so I get the following:

400, u'Bad Request'

Comment: @AndrewFerguson: show `print client` to see what arguments `GetMessage()` expects

Comment: Updated the original with the print value

Comment: Hey Andrew Ferguson, did you got the answer for this question, I mean I am also facing the same problem i.e Exception: (400, u'Bad Request'), and not getting any solution